# Trouble loading kernel 3.18

Tags: kernel

I received 3.18 in apt update but it does not show up on recovery list and I cant seem to get the missing parts. How do I get 3.18 to load?

Comment: How exactly did you recieve kernel 3.18 in ubungu updates? Latest Ubuntu release uses 3.16.

Answer (score 0):

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.18-rc1-utopic/linux-headers-3.18.0-031800rc1_3.18.0-031800rc1.201410192135_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.18-rc1-utopic/linux-headers-3.18.0-031800rc1-generic_3.18.0-031800rc1.201410192135_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.18-rc1-utopic/linux-image-3.18.0-031800rc1-generic_3.18.0-031800rc1.201410192135_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.18*.deb linux-image-3.18*.deb

This should do the job